# equals() method in apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to compare Sheets and I just noticed there is no equals() method in the class. It extends Iterable but if I have a custom made Pojo with a sheet inside, and make/override an equals() method, it will probably fail.

Does this mean I need to make a custom made "equals" that iterates over all the Rows/Cells?

Why doesn't Sheet have a equals()?
Thanks

(source: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html)

Comment: Just guessing here: probably that comparison is pretty expensive and people didn't want to default to that.

Comment: Just to add +info, neither Sheet, Row or Cell have any equals(). I cannot believe Cell.equals() would be expensive.

Comment: `Sheet` is an interface. Usually, interfaces do not declare standard methods (like `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` etc.) Perhaps, you want to ask why its implementations do not override `Object.equals`

Comment: @defaultlocale you are right. All are interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement it yourself.

My guess is that the equlas method was not implemented because:

- It might be expensive (as @GhostCat suggests) and
- It is not 100% clear how it should be implemented:

  - Someone just wants to compare the Sheets' names (for map lookups etc), someone wants to compare all cells.
  - And when comparing cells, someone wants to separate between plain values and values derived from formulas while someone doesn't care.
  - Someone considers an empty cell and a non-defined cell equal, while someone else doesn't.
  - Etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `simple-excel` to do that (please, find the [GIT](https://github.com/tobyweston/simple-excel) project). Please, find an example in their [blog](http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2012/09/14/diff-excel-with-java-and-hamcrest/):

```
Workbook actual = new HSSFWorkbook(...);
Workbook expected = new HSSFWorkbook(...);
assertThat(actual, sameWorkbook(expected));
```

Using that, you will have useful information in case both sheets are not equal:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: entire workbook to be equal
     but: cell at "C14" contained <"bananas"> expected <nothing>,
          cell at "C15" contained <"£1,850,000"> expected <"£1,850,000.00">,
          cell at "D16" contained <nothing> expected <"Tue Sep 04 06:30:00">
```